# Django form using choices against a queryset causes error if part of initial makemigrations

Tags: django

I would like to understand best practice for this issue.

I have a Django form with something like:

```
class AdvancedSearchForm(forms.Form):
    CATEGORY_OPTIONS = Category.objects.all().order_by('parent_id','primary')

    categoryAS = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget = forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                     'onchange' : 'changeCategory("id_categoryAS");'}),
        label = '',
        required = False,
        choices = ((x.id, x.primary) for x in CATEGORY_OPTIONS),
        )
```

If this is the first `makemigrations` I run for the project I invariably find I get an error message telling me `Cateogry.parent_id` doesn't exist.  In order to run it I need to comment out the choices line, run `makemigrations` and `migrate` and then uncomment the choices line.

Is this standard practice or what practice should I follow to ensure it works first time.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Django 1.8+, you can use a callable for choices.

```
def get_choices():
    return ((x.id, x.primary) for x in AdvancedSearchForm.CATEGORY_OPTIONS),

class AdvancedSearchForm(forms.Form):
    CATEGORY_OPTIONS = Category.objects.all().order_by('parent_id','primary')

    categoryAS = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_choices)
```

The `get_choices` method runs when the form is created in the view, rather than when the module is loaded. This means you won't have any problems when running initial migrations.

Sometimes, it is possible to use a `ModelChoice` instead of a `ChoiceField`. The queryset is not evaluated until the form is initialised, so you won't have any problems when running initial migrations.

```
class AdvancedSearchForm(forms.Form):
    CATEGORY_OPTIONS = Category.objects.all()

    categoryAS = forms.ModelChoiceForm(choices=CATEGORY_OPTIONS)
```

You can even customize the labels of the model choice field, by subclassing it and overriding `label_from_instance`.

```
from django import forms

class MyModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return self.primary

class AdvancedSearchForm(forms.Form):
    CATEGORY_OPTIONS = Category.objects.all()

    categoryAS = MyModelChoiceForm(choices=CATEGORY_OPTIONS)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [forms.ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield). You’d then use the “queryset” attribute instead of “choices”.

Answer (score 0):

Its due to app registry initialization.This error can be solve by using several methods.

1 ) Use `ModelChoiceField` instead of `ChoiceField`.

2 ) Django cannot execute queries during the initialization of the app registry so instead of that directly giving queryset ,create a function and assign that to choices.

Comment: `only`, `defer` and `values` won't help for initial migrations -- the table won't exist in the database at all. Options 1 and 3 are much better.

Comment: Yes 1 and 3 are better ones, but in some case if you added only one field in your table and you are making migrations then excluding this field via Skill.objects.only('id','name') in form queryset will not give you error.